# mapreduce program to read data from hive

Tags: mapreduce, hive

I am new to hadoop mapreduce and hive. 
I would like to read data from Hive using Mapreduce program(in java) and identify the average. 
I am not sure how to implement in mapreduce. Please help me with sample program.
I am using ibm biginsights 64-bit to work on hadoop framework.

And I am unable to refer below link. Getting page cannot be found error.
https://cwiki.apache.org/Hive/tutorial.html#Tutorial-Custommap%252Freducescripts

Answer (score 0):

`enter code here`Is there a reason you are not simply using hql  and

```
select avg(my_col) from my_table?
```

If you really need to do it in Java  then you can use HiveClient and access via the hive jdbc api.

Here is a sample code snippet (elaborated from the HiveClient docs):

```
    Connection con = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    Resulset rs = null;
    try {
    con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive://localhost:10000/default", "", "");
    stmt = con.createStatement();
    rs  = stmt.executeQuery("select avg(my_col) as my_avg from my_table");
    Double avg = rs.getDouble("my_avg");
    // do something with it..
   } finally {
       // close rs, stmt, conn in reverse order
   }
```

For further info:  https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveClient

Note: you do NOT need to put this code into YOUR map/reduce  Hive takes care of creating the map/reduce program (and the associated benefits of parallelization) itself.